# Como eu atualizo os dados? Ionic2

Tags: html, ionic2, atualização

Olá!

Comecei a aprender programação há pouco tempo e estou utilizando a framework "Ionic2".
Porém, gostaria de saber como eu faço pra poder atualizar os dados. Por exemplo:
Eu criei um aplicativo de Star Wars e amanhã precisaria adicionar um novo jedi. Como isso é possível sem ter que mexer em todo o código HTML?
Sou leigo no assunto, então me perdoem se isso for algo simples.

Comment: A tua pergunta não é clara. O que pretendes fazer? A tua aplicação tem base de dados, ou apenas queres adicionar dados?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tua pergunta não é clara. O que pretendes fazer?

A tua aplicação tem base de dados, ou apenas queres adicionar dados?

Vê este link, tem as melhores práticas https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-conference-app, como também sugiro ires ver alguns tutorials no youtube ou https://ionicframework.com/getting-started/ para teres uma melhor noção do que pretendes fazer e do que podes fazer.

Comment: Minha dúvida é: Crio um app e preciso postar notícias diárias. Como ionic é híbrido, se eu atualizar os dados HTML dele, logo as notícias se atualizam no sistema e todos podem ver? Ou eu preciso atualizar por outros lugares?